# Change ValidationSummary Template to add text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, validationsummary, editortemplates, display-templates

Using MVC 4/Razor

`@HTML.ValidationSummary(True)` generates:

> - First Name is required.
> - Last Name is required.

`@HTML.ValidationSummary(True, "Please fix the following errors:")` generates:

> **Please fix the following errors:**
>
> - First Name is required.
> - Last Name is required.

I want to be able to default the "Please fix the following errors" so that putting
`@HTML.ValidationSummary(True)` would generate:

> **Please fix the following errors:**
>
> - First Name is required.
> - Last Name is required.

Is there anyway to do that? I have this but have no idea where to put it:

```
 @model ModelStateDictionary
    @using System.Web.Mvc.Html
    @using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

    <div class='@(Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid ? "validation-summary-valid" : "validation-summary-errors") data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <span><strong>Please fix the following errors:</strong></span>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var modelError in Model.SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors))
            {
                <li>@modelError.ErrorMessage</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
```